# String extraction in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string like that

"Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014"

I want to extract string before and after the pipe sybmol . How can I do it?

Comment: A little of research could easily avoid this kind of questions. Look at string.Split.There are thousands of answer about this

Comment: `string s = "Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014";
 var array = s.Split('|');
 Console.WriteLine(array[0].Trim());
 Console.WriteLine(array[1].Trim());
 Console.WriteLine(array[2].Trim());` Here a [`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/fYKOd7).

Comment: Read about string.split and string.IndexOf - string.Substring

Answer (score 2):

You can use string methods like `String.Substring`/`String.Remove` or `String.Split`:

```
string text = "Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014";
string before = text;
string after = "";
int indexOfPipe = text.IndexOf('|');
if (indexOfPipe >= 0)
{
    before = text.Remove(indexOfPipe).Trim();
    after = text.Substring(indexOfPipe + 1).Trim();
}
```

I assume that you want both dates in the second string: `20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014`. By the way, if you want real `DateTime`s you need to use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
string[] bothDates = after.Split('|');
DateTime[] bothDateTimes = bothDates
    .Select(str => DateTime.Parse(str.Trim()))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Split()`:

```
string info = "Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014";
var strings = info.Split('|');
string title = strings[0];
string date = strings[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014";
string[] strArray = str.Split('|');
for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(strArray[i].Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**String.Split()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method:

```
var input = "Monsoon Season | 20-05-2014 | 06-10-2014";
var parts = input.Split('|');
```

`parts` is now a string array containing `Monsoon Season`, `20-05-2014` and `06-10-2014`.

Answer (score -3):

use

```
string.split('|')
```

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

hope that helps

Split takes char as parameter

Comment: Am not downvoter. but It's hard to believe this code works for you.

Comment: `string.split("|")` will not even *compile* in C#.  Not only is your example wrong, but it's woefully incomplete.  And your attitude is less than impressive.

Comment: I guess ur abusing in last line right?